# Return value based on count in a case query

Tags: oracle, select, count, case

i'm looking forward to your opinion about this request, it seems super simple but I can not figure it out alone.

If the table column part_status has one value, return it; else return 'many'.

**Scenario 1 Table data:**

```
Part_Status
'A'
'A'
'A'
```

Returns

```
Part_Status
'A'
```

**Scenario 2 Table data:**

```
Part_Status
'A'
```

Return col1 value, here

```
Part_Status
'A'
```

**Scenario 3 Table data:**

```
Part_Status
'A'
'E'
```

Return value

```
Part_Status
'Many'
```

First idea was to use case and if the amount of count is greater 1 return 'many' but it is never printed:

```
select DISTINCT case
     when count(PART_STATUS) > 1 THEN
      'MANY'
     ELSE
      PART_STATUS
   end
from (select DISTINCT Part_Status
      from Inventory_Part
     where part_status IN ('A','E')
     )
GROUP BY PART_STATUS
```

Returns

```
Part_Status
'A'
'E'
```

In the second idea I got 'Many' working but the single result is NULL

```
select CASE
     WHEN COUNT(PART_STATUS) > 1 THEN
      'Many'
   end AS "PART_STATUS"
FROM (select DISTINCT Part_Status
      from Inventory_Part
     where part_status IN ('A', 'E'))
```

Returns

```
Part_Status 
'Many'
```

So, how to combine both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SQL> with test (part_status) as
  2    (select 'A' from dual union all
  3     select 'A' from dual
  4    )
  5  select distinct
  6         case when (select count(distinct part_status) from test) > 1 then 'Many'
  7              else part_status
  8         end
  9  from test;

CASE
----
A
```

---

```
SQL> with test (part_status) as
  2    (select 'A' from dual union all
  3     select 'E' from dual
  4    )
  5  select distinct
  6         case when (select count(distinct part_status) from test) > 1 then 'Many'
  7              else part_status
  8         end
  9  from test;

CASE
----
Many

SQL>
```

Comment: Let me check. I will come back to you later today! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it. Anyway, I'm not convinced that It is the smart way.

```
select CASE
         when "cnt" > 1 THEN
          'Many'
         when "cnt" = 1 THEN
          PART_STATUS
       end
  from (select rownum AS "cnt", PART_STATUS
          FROM (select DISTINCT Part_Status
                  from Inventory_Part
                 where part_status IN ('A', 'E'))
         ORDER BY ROWNUM DESC)

 fetch first row only
```